# Javascript event handling and call stack issue/memory leak

Tags: javascript, event-handling, components, callstack

I have a problem with events creating an evergrowing callstack in modularised javascript.

The aim is to build encapsulated components as javascript modules that monitor and update themselves. Vanilla Javascript only (no frameworks) using a revealing module pattern to ensure a clean namespace and protect the component content.

The problem laid out below can be seen via the Console.trace(), which shows an ever-extending call stack. Each time an Event is fired, the subsequent event runs as a daughter call of the original function. Changing scope with bind() doesn't help as it seems purely callstack related. What's the best method for preventing the callstack filling up?

HTML for where the component will be

```
<div id='demoMe'>
    <p>Encapsulated module below.</p>
</div>
```

Create and initiate a javascript component on the #demoMe element. Want to minimise Javascript in the global scope - could be a whole app being initiated, not just a component.

```
var myComponent=new myComponent;
myComponent.load({ pages: ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday", "Saturday","Sunday"] });
myComponent.init("#demoMe");
```

The component has load and init as standard component interface. The idea being that the component manages itself retaining data and settings. Note this is just the most simple example of the problem I could use as an illustration.

```
function myComponent() {
    var privateParams;
    var privatePageno=0;
    var targetElt;
    var actionButtonElt;
    
    function init(elt) {
        targetElt=document.querySelector(elt);
        show();
        setObservers();
    }

    function load(in_params) {
        // Add parameters
        privateParams=in_params;
    }
    
    function show() {
        // Display the item
        let actionButton=" <i class='clickMe'>Click me</i>";
        let displayElt=document.createElement("div");
        let addText="";
        if(privatePageno==5) {
            addText=" (Weeeeekeeennddd!)";
        }
        displayElt.innerHTML="<p id='pg"+privatePageno+"'>" +
                                privateParams.pages[privatePageno] +
                                addText + actionButton +
                              "</p>";
        targetElt.appendChild(displayElt);
        actionButtonElt=displayElt.querySelector(".clickMe");
    }
    
    function update(evnt) {
        console.trace();    // PROBLEM IS HERE
        privatePageno++;
        if(privatePageno>=privateParams.pages.length) {
            privatePageno=0;
        }
        // Update/extend the component on the page
        show();  
        setObservers();     // After update the call stack changes
    }
    
    function setObservers() {
        // This could be a form submit for instance 
        actionButtonElt.addEventListener('click',update);
    }
    
    return({
        load:load,
        init:init
    });
}
```